# Horizontal & vertically centered div 'jumping' when an image is appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Question Background:**

I have a simple view consisting of a Form, a button and some text. Through CSS i have horizontally and vertically centered the contents of the page.

**The Issue:**

When a user clicks onto the button I am appending a spinner .gif image to a div. The issue I have currently is as the content is centered appending the image causes the form to move up which dosen't look good.

**Code Pen example:**

Please see my codepen for a demo of the issue

http://codepen.io/daveharris/pen/dMvaGW

HTML:

```
 <div id="centerDiv" class="centered">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-centered pushDown">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group text-center">
              A HomePage Item
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group text-center">
              A HomePage Item

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group text-center">

              A HomePage Item
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h4>This is homepage text</h4>
          </div>

          <div id="loadSpinner" class="text-center">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pushDown {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.spinnerSize {
  height: 60px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
}
```

JavaScript & jQuery:

```
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(){

          var spinner = '<img src="http://i870.photobucket.com/albums/ab267/GLaDOS_Chibi/Aperture_Science_by_crazychrislau93.gif" class="spinnerSize">';

          $('#loadSpinner').append(spinner);
     });
```

**How can I go about changing this so the contents is still vertically/horizontally centered by when the button is click and spinner append it dosen't cause the contents to jump up?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give `#loadSpinner` a corresponding height of `60px`. This will get rid of the "jumping":

```
#loadSpinner {  
  height:60px;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKmPqx)**

Comment: Perfect, cant believe I didn't think of that!